# Exactly how does Suleiman's special work?

Tags: civilization-5

Playing Ottoman for the first time and I seem to have far less than 50% conversion of naval barbarians via barbary corsairs. The description merely says there is a 50% conversion rate however and doesn't specify what triggers this so I suspect I'm doing something wrong/

Comment: Similar question asked here: http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?91131-Ottoman-Special-Ability&highlight=Ottoman

Comment: I have no idea how it works. I already have captured 14 barbarian naval units, and still no achievement... :-(

Comment: Okay - now I have 20 barb units. No achievement. Grrr... Anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you get near a barbarian naval unit with your own unit the special ability works. If you are lucky then the barbarian naval unit is converted. If not nothing changes you can attack.

Comment: from experiments this seems correct, also if it didnt work going away and coming back to it doesn't seem to trigger it for a second shot